# How to link a subform to a combobox on the main form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, subform, adp

On a form in an access ADP  there is an unbound combobox that displays a list of companies (the name is shown, the id is the bound field). When a company is chosen, I want to display the subscription information in a subform (the datasource for which is companySubscription view) for that company. I set the link Master Fields and links child Fields property of the subform to the companyId. Basically, I set it up [like this](http://www.cbe.wwu.edu/ganz/mis421web/accesstips.htm).

In theory, I would think this would mean that when I change the value in the combobox the subform should show the subscription information for that company. It isn't working though- the subform always shows all the data in the companySubscription view, no matter what the combobox is set to.

Comment: Do you know how to switch the parent form's current record based on what is chosen in the combobox?

Comment: @Hansup The link master field does not have to be a field, it can be a control, and the control can even hold straight text. I have used this often.

Comment: I suspect that the problem may be with the bound column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer- had some code from another project that helped:

```
Private Sub cmbSub_AfterUpdate()
    ' Find the record that matches the control.
    Dim rs As Object

    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[subID] = " & str(Nz(Me![cmbSub], 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

And had to modify it for an ADP (thanks to [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/36115564/find-record-on-form-in-ado.aspx) post!)

```
Private Sub ChooseCo_AfterUpdate()
    ' Find the record that matches the control.
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.Find "[companyId] = " & Str(Nz(Me![ChooseCo], 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the code produced by the combo box wizard when you choose to create a FIND combo box. I don't know about the ADP version, but the first one is one of the worst pieces of auto-generated code in existence. I tear it to shreds in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401645/how-do-i-bring-up-a-record-based-on-a-combobox-in-access/3418490#3418490 -- in that article I find "an error rate of at least 2.5 problems per line of code created". My criticism is for code in an MDB/ACCDB, but 75% of the criticism apply in an ADP, too -- it's really crappy code.