# MS Access: Choose a option from ComboBox and it automatically updats other text box

Tags: ms-access, combobox

What I want to do is choose a option from a combobox- (i.e. a Person ID), and based on that option the form auto populates other text boxes (Person Name, Location, Number)

I have a table with the information. the table contains the person ID along with the the person's information in each record. The table contains 1400 records.

Any EASY WAY to do this. All answers are appreciated. even difficult ones.

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/videos/video-find-a-record-on-a-form-by-selecting-a-value-from-a-list-VA101842893.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401645/how-do-i-bring-up-a-record-based-on-a-combobox-in-access/3404509#3404509, amongst numerous others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a subform whose record source is a query such as this ...

```
SELECT [Person ID], [Person Name], Location, [Number]
FROM The_Table;
```

Then, from the subform control's property sheet, select the main form's combo box as the link master field and [Person ID] as the link child field.  The result should be that the subform displays those additional details for the ID currently selected in the combo box.

That is an easy way to *display* the details.  If your intention was to *store* those details again in another table, I'll suggest don't do that.  Store only the ID and then if you need to display the details in other contexts, use a query to join (based on ID) the two tables.

Comment: is it possible to have that information uploaded to the main form when it is saved?

Comment: Its related. You told me i should just store the person id. I want the information from the subform stored (i.e. person name location) onto the database.

Comment: I understand now.  The answer I offered is not what you want.  If you will unaccept my answer I can delete it.  Without an accepted answer, your question has a better chance of getting the answer you want.

Comment: No but it is a. Good. Alt. Ty

Comment: By the way i went with this method. TY